# Probability concerning summation of independent trials

Tags: probability, summation

I am have a very hard time solving this particular question. If anyone can help my understanding by providing a helpful solution, it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Consider n independent trials, each of which results in one of the outcomes $1, \dots , k$ with respective probabilities $p_1,\dots,p_k$, $$\sum_{i=1}^{k}p_i = 1$$
Show that if all the $p_i$ are small, then the probability that no trial outcome occurs more than once is approximately equal to

$$\exp\left(\frac{-n(n-1)}{2}\left(\sum_{i}^{}p_i^2\right)\right) $$

Comment: The answer you wish to get is missing a right parenthesis $)$. If the right parenthesis is to the right of the summation,  I suggest that you use `\left(` and `\right)` to make the parentheses more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $|j|$ denote the number of times event $j$ occurs in the $n$ trials.

In the proof below, I essentially use the inclusion exclusion principle.

---

Suppose event $i$ occurs at least twice. The probability of all such sequences is

$$P_n\{|i|\ge 2\} = \binom{n}{2} p_i^2. $$

This can be thought of as the following: Pick $2$ locations out of $n$ where event $i$ occurs. The rest are chosen arbitrarily, and summing over those choices leaves us with the above.

The probability that at least one event occurs at least twice is then *upper bounded* by

$$P_n\{\exists i : |i| \ge 2\}\le\binom{n}{2}  \sum_i p_i^2.$$

---

Now, the probability that events $i$ and $j \neq i$ occur at least twice is precisely

$$P_n\{|i|\ge 2, |j| \ge 2\} = \frac{1}{2} \binom{n}{2}\binom{n-2}{2} p_i^2 p_j^2$$

This is the same argument as before. The factor of half is introduced because the events where $i$ is placed first and then $j$ and the events where $j$ is placed first and then $i$ are the same.

Thus, the probability that at least two events occur at least twice is upper bounded by:

$$P_n\{\exists i,j : |i|, |j| \ge 2\}\le \frac{1}{2} \binom{n}{2}\binom{n-2}{2} \sum_{j\neq i}\sum_i p_i^2 p_j^2 \le \frac{1}{2}\left(\binom{n}{2}\sum_i p_i^2 \right)^2$$

Thus, the probability that precisely one event occurs more than once is *lower bounded* by
\begin{align}
 P_n\{ \exists i : |i| \ge 2\} &\ge \binom{n}{2}  \sum_i p_i^2 - \frac{1}{2}\left(\binom{n}{2}\sum_i p_i^2 \right)^2
\end{align}

This is using the inclusion-exclusion principle up to the second term, and the fact that terms are decreasing with order in the expansion therein (this may need more sophisticated justification).

---

Define $x:= \binom{n}{2} \sum_i p_i^2$. Merging the results above,

$$ 1 - x + \frac{x^2}{2} \ge P_n\{ |i|=1~\forall i\} \ge 1 - x$$

Which uses the fact that $P_n\{ |i| \le 1~\forall i\} = 1 - P_n\{ \exists i : |i| \ge 2\}$

As $x \to 0$, i.e., the regime where $\binom{n}{2}\sum p_i^2 \to 0$, both the left and right hand side tend to $\exp{-x}$. Consequently, we establish the very crude approximation:

$$P_n\{ |i| \le 1~\forall i\} \approx \exp \left( -\binom{n}{2} \left(\sum_{i \in [1:k]} p_i^2\right)\right)$$